# VueJS v-data-table Parent-Child comunication

Tags: javascript, vue.js

here I am stuck on something and I hope help:
I have two Vuetify "v-data-tables"
1 - Parent table
2 - Children's table "children's table is a reusable component"

I am looking for a piece of general code that I can adapt to my program, so I want that each time I click on a ROW in the Parent table, the data in the Child table displays the detail that matches well with ID

I looked on the net there are examples but can not adapt them to my prog. Here is the link : [enter link description here](https://github.com/spatie/vue-table-component)

```js
<template>
   <div id="app">
       <table-component :data="fetchData">
           <table-column show="firstName" label="First name"></table-column>
       </table-component>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        methods: {
            async fetchData({ page, filter, sort }) {
                const response = await axios.get('/my-endpoint', { page });

                // An object that has a `data` and an optional `pagination` property
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: use props in your child component to receive data from the parent

Comment: How can do that, please some examples. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem and I would like to share it with you then, firstly you had to use "Event bus" you would find lots of tutorial and video disappointed.
1 - j'ai créé un fichier JS nommé bus.js avec ce code :

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
export const EventBus = new Vue()
```

2- dans le composant Parent dans les Methods :

```js
EventBus.$emit('id', id)
```

"Id" est l’identificateur de la ROW sélectionner.

3- dans le second composant Enfant qui contenais le détail :

```js
EventBus.$on('id', id => {
      console.log(id)
      this.idSelect = id
      console.log('Mounted' + this.idSelect)
      this.loadContenu()
    })
```

loadcontenu est la méthode qui charge les données détail de l'API.
idSelect est une variable qui reçois ID envoyer depuis le composant Parent.

Voilà j'ai voulu partager cette petite expérience avec vous qui pourrais aider.

Answer (score 0):

just a brief example using simple props:

Parent Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div @click="passId('12345')">
        </div>
        <childComponent 
        :theId = theId
        />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import childComponent from 'path/to/your/childComponent'
export default {

    components:{
        childComponent 
    },
    data(){
        return{
            theId:null
        }
    },
    methods:{
    passId(id){
        this.theId = id    
    }
    }  
}
</script>
```

Child Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="theId">
            <!-- do something with theID here -->
        </div>
    </div> 
</template>
<script>
export default {

    props:{
        theId:{
            type: String,
            default:null
        }
    } 
}
</script>
```